# How do I cast a float to an integer datatype in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have a table in KDB(Q) with a size column that is currently in float format. How do I cast the entire column from float to int, while truncating the decimal place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by updating your table

```
q)tab:([]bid:1000?5f;price:1000?5f;size:1000?100f)
q)exec t from meta tab
"fff"
q)update "i"$size from `tab
`tab
q)exec t from meta tab
"ffi"
```

In the above the pertinent point is the application of `"i"$` which is 'casting' the size column from a float to an integer

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is using the `@` [amend](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/) to update the column(s):

```
q)t:([]sym:500?`3;px:500?10f;size:500?100f)
q)3#t
sym px       size
---------------------
gdh 7.678514 95.25017
jlb 2.345028 42.09728
nln 5.553286 98.80532
q)t:@[t;`size;"i"$] / can also use `t to update t
q)3#t
sym px       size
-----------------
gdh 7.678514 95
jlb 2.345028 42
nln 5.553286 98
```

I think its also worth pointing out that floor/ceiling functions round numbers down/up respectively and works slightly faster than `"i"$` in this case, however these functions cast the column to a long instead of an int:

```
q)meta@[t;`size;floor]
c   | t f a
----| -----
sym | s
px  | f
size| j
```